# How to make nodejs read another file in the same folder after log in

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make the system read another file in the same folder so that it can render the next `HTML`.

However, it shows me this error.

> Cannot GET
> /function%20router(req,%20res,%20next)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20router.handle(req,%20res,%20next);%0A%20%20%7D

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const agentRoutes = require("./agent");

router.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.render("login.html");
});
router.post("/auth", function(request, response) {
    const { username, password } = request.body;
    if (username == 1 && password == 1) {
        return response.redirect(agentRoutes);
    } else {
        return response.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth fail",
        });
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: what do you mean by reading another file? what do you want to achieve? the error you're shown is not related to the code you wrote

Comment: I am trying to access agent.js in the same folder which can show the html for agents. Because initially I use response.redirect to the direct html but it cannot receive the inputs I did to the button of html. So I am not sure is it due to routing issue or it is not reading the function in the folder because it never show any error message and output

Answer (score 0):

`response.redirect()` requires the string you want to redirect to, not the router itself.

```
return response.redirect('/');
```